# What does setup_postdata ($post ) do?

Tags: get-posts

The codex defines it as 'Set up global post data. Helps to format custom query results for using Template tags.' I don't really understand this.

Here is a code example :

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach( $posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
echo $post->ID;
endforeach;
```

Please can you explain?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Template tag functions rely on global variables to access the post being processed and retrieve data from it or related to it.

The main variable among these is `$post`, which holds the post object itself.

In your example it's not explicit, but what is happening is that your loop assigns data to `$post`. If its name wasn't `$post`, you would need to name it explicitly (`global $post; $post = $some_other_post;`).

However, there are a bunch of other globals and the purpose of [`setup_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_postdata/) is to fill them with data. If you look at the source, these are:

```
global $id, $authordata, $currentday, $currentmonth, $page, $pages, $multipage, $more, $numpages;
```

Note that in most cases you should be calling [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_postdata/) afterwards to return globals to their original state.